# Import an updated GitHub repository without breaking a modified/outdated version of it in vendor directory

Tags: go, govendor

Previously, a GitHub repository is got inside `vendor/github.com` directory, actually `~/go/src/myapp/vendor/github.com`. It is modified and imported in some packages. So, it is both outdated and modified.

Now, in some other packages, I need to import and use the original GitHub repository i.e. updated and unmodified. How can I do that? What are my options? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Did you modify the code in `vendor`? Do you commit `vendor`? // Gomod dependency manager solves the problem of having multiple major versions in the same lib.

Comment: @bgnfu7re The code in `vendor` is modified and committed.

Comment: Do you use any dependency managers? One way is to actually fork and version the original library and then use both modified and original.

Comment: @bgnfu7re As far as I'm aware, there is no dependency manager used right now. But that's a nice idea to fork the GitHub repository in my GitHub account and then import it =)